# how to re-read message from apache Kafka if kafka streams application which are consuming the messages have some exception

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm reading messages from kafka using kafka streams for real time processing.
Then, I'm sending this message to other rest api(Final service), if there is an error while calculating the message in final service, it will throw an error back to main service.
In main service, now , i would like to re-read those messages after a particular interval of time or instantly on the basis of scenario.

Scenarios -

- If final service is not working, connection timeout exception. In this case, the messages should be re-tried after a particular time interval.
- If there is some technical exception, then the message should be re-processed instantly.

[image: Attaching the image for better clarification]

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/52779815/1911941 this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not committing the consumed record, you'd simply restart the app. However, to immediately retry the request to the final API, you must write the code to do that, for every consumed record from Kafka; Kafka Streams will only try to deliver the record to your API client once.

Otherwise, you need to seek the consumer group backward, as mentioned in the comments, or use `kafka-consumer-groups --reset-offsets` CLI for **each topic** that may be part of your topology.

Side note: Kafka Streams should not be used to make synchronous request/reply calls to external endpoints. Use Kafka Connect or Consumer API with tighter offset handling for this